# document.querySelector selects the first row always

Tags: angularjs

This is the tr tag inside a tbody- (displays around 20 rows, on loop)

```
<tr class="rowClass" ng-click="$ctrl.onRowClick(row[0]);" ng-class="" ng-repeat="row in $ctrl.rows track by $index">
```

By default it shows a blue background for the rows on hover. Clicking on a row opens up a panel, and what I'm working on is that if I click on a row it should show a solid blue background until the panel is closed.

So onRowClick adds newClass (with solid blue background)-

```
ctrl.onRowClick = function (row) {
    var myElement = angular.element( document.querySelector( '.rowClass' ) );
myElement.addClass('newClass');
}
```

closePanel removes the newClass and it goes back to the default hover class-

```
function closePanel(){
    var myElement = angular.element( document.querySelector( '.rowClass' ) );
    myElement.removeClass('newClass');
}
```

(Both the above functions are inside the js controller file)

This is the css I'm using-

```
.detection-table .table>tbody>tr:hover{background-color: rgba(0, 147, 237, 0.1);}
.detection-table .table>tbody>tr.newClass{background-color: rgba(0, 147, 237, 0.1);}
```

The thing that is bugging me is that if I click on any row, the newClass get triggered but always for only the first row and not the particular row that I clicked on.
Should I change something in **document.querySelector( '.rowClass' )** ?

Comment: well, yes, because `document.querySelector( '.rowClass' )` will ***always*** select the first `.rowClass` that it finds. that is its job. Maybe you should start your selection based on the element that was clicked or one of it's ancestors rather than the document.

Comment: What i'd suggest doing is instead of trying to target the element, alter the data, and have that change cause the change in css to occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`element.querySelector` will return the first node that matches the selector in **DOM traversal order**. Your element here is `document`. You don't always have to call this on document. You can say `anotherElem.querySelector(someSelector)` or `event.currentTarget.querySelector(someSelector)`. In your case why don't you just use `this` or `event.currentTarget` ? or I terribly missed something.

Comment: I was wrong, `row` is an item in the array being iterated over, not an element.

Comment: Do you mean I should use something like var myElement = angular.element( this.querySelector( '.rowClass' ) ); and then do an addClass over it? I'm sorry if this sound wrong but I'm struggling a bit here.

Comment: is there a way you can reach to the event inside your `onRowClick`?

Comment: If I do a console.log(row) inside it, I can get the entire row data that is clicked on.

Comment: You are not using "row" within your callback anyway, can you do this `ng-click="$ctrl.onRowClick($event);"`  What does it console log??

Comment: it gives me r.Event object and a number of attributes inside it

Comment: Aha! I suspect then that `event.currentTarget` is your element (myElement) So: markup : `ng-click="$ctrl.onRowClick($event);"` handler:  `ctrl.onRowClick = function (event) {
    var myElement = angular.element( event.currentTarget );
myElement.addClass('newClass');
}`

Comment: Ok so do I make the same change to closeCallback function? Cos right now the blue background is still there even if I close the panel

Comment: Just used the document.querySelectorAll for that and it works as intended now. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170186/discussion-between-manishk-and-ibowankenobi).